# Cast screen on Samsung Television from Moto G7

Tags: samsung, 9.0-pie, motorola, smart-tv

I have a Samsung smart TV. I want to cast the screen of my *Moto G7 Power* running Android 9 onto the TV. I have made sure that the TV and the cell phone are on the same Wi-Fi system. When I go to Connected Devices -> Connection preferences -> Cast, then I can't find my TV there. However, when I try the same thing with my *Nokia 6.1 Plus* then I can find my TV there and can easily cast my screen. Also, when I cast from within the Youtube app on *Moto G7*, then I can find my TV and can successfully cast just the video being played on the app (but this doesn't cast the entire screen). Has anyone experienced something similar? is there some settings that I need to change to be able to cast the entire screen of my Moto G7?

Also, I don't own a Chromecast and don't want to purchase one either. I want to make my Moto work the same way the Nokia does.

Comment: May be this a problem of the display resolution? The Moto G7 Power has 1570 x 720 and the Nokia 6.1 has 1920 x 1080. The latter therefore exactly matches a Full-HD TV resolution.

Comment: Thanks! But that still sounds less plausible explanation because (1) it works from within Youtube app (2) the TV doesn't even appear when I search for devices from within the Cast feature of the phone. I would guess that in case of such an incompatibility (as you suggest) I should have received an error message *after* I try to pair the devices.

Comment: Youtube provides different streams with different resolutions, independently of your phone screen size. All those streams are compatible to a common resolution like FullHD. Therefore the Youtube cast stream will be totally different to the one generated by casting your screen.

Comment: [Edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/216875/edit) your post to include the model number of Samsung Smart TV (even firmware version if possible). I've had issues with my Samsung Smart TV not being found/not behaving correctly and my "fix" is to unplug the TV, wait 30 sec, plug it back in. You may want to try that with each phone (i.e. pair & cast after TV reboot) and see if it does anything.

Answer (score 1):

In order to mirror your Motorola smartphone's screen onto a Samsung smart TV (assuming both devices are equipped with the necessary features, some are not) you must connect the devices together using WiFi Direct.

I have no idea why this is the only way it works. I wish that the manufacturers (product & feature designers) of our (smart) devices would understand that in order for features to be useful for their customers, they MUST actually work. A fundamental & crucial aspect of functionality (working) is compatibility across devices, brands & OSes/OS versions. If proprietary features exist only compatible with the same brand and they functionally replace some feature or capability native in the OS, that is asinine & unhelpful.

The solution/workaround to this discrepancy is very inconvenient. This is also completely unnecessary. The designers could have simply used the features incorporated in the OS. Or they could have tested their devices and come up with patches to resolve the issue.